# What is the Python interpolate function which is the same as spapi in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation, spline

In Matlab, I can use the spline interpolation function `spapi` to generate a spline curve, so that prescribed values of the curves and its first two derivatives can be matched. For example:

```
spapi([0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2],[0 1 1 1 2],[2 0 1 2 -1])
```

this produces the unique cubic spline f on the interval [0..2] with exactly one interior knot, at 1, that satisfies the five conditions

> f(0)=2, f(1)=0, f'(1)=1, f''(1)=2, f(2)=–1

These include 3-fold matching at 1, i.e., matching there to prescribed values of the function and its first two derivatives.

In Python, however, the spline interpolate function `scipy.interpolate.splrep(x,y)` can not work as `x` should be monotone increasing.

So, how can I get a curve with prescribed values and derivative values? Is there any Python moldue or function?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.interpolate.BPoly.from_derivatives`
constructs a Hermite spline where you can select the values of the derivatives:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BPoly.from_derivatives.html

In your example you'd have two intervals, 0..1 and 1..2.